# Add custom class to mvc3 (not inside views, controller or model folder)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I am currently new in asp.net and mvc3. I need to add class to connect to system.data.sqlclient and some class to connect to other dll. I couldn't call the class. It is in AppCode (Not APP_CODE) and couldn't call it from controller, view and model. Please somebody help me..

Comment: show us your class declaration ( namespace also)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the class's namespace as one of your 'using' statements? Is your class public?

EDIT:

You are not able to use your class because it is an 'abstract' class. You need to either implement a class that inherits from your abstract class and you that, or make your class not abstract.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;

namespace hr
{
    public abstract class DataAccess
    {
        private const string REFERENCE_CONNECTION_STRING_KEY = "Reference.Connection";
        public static string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[REFERENCE_CONNECTION_STRING_KEY];
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Give us controller file where you try to use this class.

Comment: Thx. I've succeeded. I made the APPCODE not APP_CODE cause APP_CODE is executed after MVC. Now i could make any C# Class I need. Thx so much..

Comment: If this was helpful to you, would you mind upticking my answer and/or accepting my answer? This way I can get credit and the question will be closed. Thanks.